# Call optional proc only if proc was set

Tags: ruby, proc, crystal-lang

So I am porting a tool from ruby were a callback block could be defined on an object and I want it to be called in case the callback was set.
So basically something like this.

```ruby
def set_block(&block)
  @new_kid_on_the_block = block
end

def call_the_block_if_it_was_defined
  block.call("step by step") if block = @new_kid_on_the_block
end
```

I am pretty sure this is an easy task but somehow I just run into problems.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what is the question? `block.call("step by step") if block = @new_kid_on_the_block` could just be `@new_kid_on_the_block.call("step by step") if @new_kid_on_the_block`

Comment: Are you looking for crystal code or ruby code for this?

Comment: ah yes, I meant in Crystal of course! Of course the binding to the local variable is pretty useless — my fault!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Crystal you almost always have to specify types of instance variables explicitly. So here is how it could look:

```
class A
  alias BlockType = String -> String

  def set_block(&block : BlockType)
    @block = block
  end

  def call_block
    @block.try &.call("step by step")
  end
end

a = A.new
pp a.call_block # => nil
a.set_block { |a| a + "!" }
pp a.call_block # => "step by step!"
```

Take a look at [Capturing blocks](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/capturing_blocks.html) for more.

Comment: The line `block : BlockType?` does nothing, did you forgot a `@`? (or simply emove it)

Comment: Also, you can use `def set_block(&@block : BlockType); end` (directly assign `@block` in the param)

Comment: Good catch. Removed that line ;)

Comment: @bew I am aware about `&@block` syntax but wanted to be closer to the OP's code in a question. Thanks for comment!